# How to make pngs into tilemap and sprites for unity

Tags: unity, png, tilesets

I have a tilemap in png form from Pyxel Edit I want to put in Unity. I tried to just use the png but I realized I can't do that and am now stuck.

The backgrounds are not there because I used a decent software for the art but I have not got the foggiest clue as to how to make a tileset using the pngs. Unfortunately most of the replies here about pngs to tilesets are about Pygame which I am not using.

Here is an image of the tileset I made:

[image: the tiles in question]

Comment: "I realized I can't do that" - what specific obstacle did you encounter? I've used pngs in tilesets in Unity quite often, with no specific barrier, so I'm not sure what problem you need help solving.

Comment: There are as well quite a few tutorial that cover this topics, including one from Unity itself: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-tilemaps